# How to control in Grails app which server to consume a RabbitMQ queue

Tags: grails, queue, load-balancing, rabbitmq

We have a Grails app running, and we are using the RabbitMQ plugin for exchanging messages within the application. On the production environment, we have two instances of the application deployed on two servers and we have configured 10 queue consumers per instance. I would love to be able to have only one of the servers consuming messages from the queue. I have found this configuration parameter:

***exclusive**: Only the client that created the queue can connect to it.*

and I am trying to make it work. I am not exactly sure, what do they mean by "client"...Server? App instance? Consumer?

Any other ideas on controlling the queue's consumption?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be 2 "exclusive" fields in [the spec](http://www.amqp.org/confluence/download/attachments/720900/amqp0-9-1.xml?version=1&modificationDate=1227526672000):

> queue.declare: field exclusive:
>   "Exclusive queues may only be accessed
>   by the current connection, and are
>   deleted when that connection closes.
>   Passive declaration of an exclusive
>   queue by other connections are not
>   allowed."
>
> basic.consume: field exclusive:
>   "Request exclusive consumer access,
>   meaning only this consumer can access
>   the queue."

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Robin for your answer! This is really interesting and useful info. However, since time was pressing, we bypassed this issue and provided a different implementation which did not have to deal with this issue.